# Regex php: check if string is wrapped by " or contains 2 wrapped words on each side

Tags: php, regex

please help me write regex to check if string is wrapped by double quotes or string is not wrapped? but contains on each side words that is wrapped by double quotes.

Examles:

1. `"text text text "text" text"` - wrapped string
2. `text "text" text` - not wrapped string with wrapped word inside
3. `"text" text text text "text"` - not wrapped string, but contains wrapped words on each side (`" text text text "` is not wrapped string)

Thank you!

Comment: And you have what code to show so far?

Comment: You'd really need to expand on what constitutes a wrapped string if the quotes aren't escaped.  You could easily argue 3 is a wrapped string with `" text text text "` as the middle.

Comment: In case 1 can we find any number of double quotes inside the wrapped string? may `" text text text "` be a wrapped string for case 2?

Comment: I don't have time to keep on working with this, but just for fun I tried to see if one can see a pattern by doing this https://3v4l.org/sjrre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This correctly matches your sample inputs.  `/^"[^ ].*[^ ]"$/`

If you have other samples where this pattern doesn't hold up please post those sample strings.

https://regex101.com/r/GBAvlw/2

If you have larger bodies of text that your sample inputs exist inside of, we need to know that.